# Spring-mvc + Spring-Security + Thymeleaf - Error Resolving Template

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm following a simple online tutorial for building a Spring + Spring Security + Thymeleaf + Maven project and I'm getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] [tomcat-http--4 02:00:16] (TemplateEngine.java:process:1085) [THYMELEAF][tomcat-http--4] Exception processing template "login": Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
Feb 24, 2015 2:00:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/hub] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:146)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:279)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It looks like for some reason it is not resolving the login page but even though the login page is at the correct location. If I point to the users.html page that page loads and there are no errors. Must be something very simple I'm missing out on. Can someone please assist?

The following are my config classes:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    //Load application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(ApplicationContext.class);
    rootContext.setDisplayName("hub");

    //Context loader listener 
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    //Dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = 
            servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1); 
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

ApplicationContext class:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.motodoc.hub.*"})
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({SpringDataConfig.class, ThymeleafConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class})
@ImportResource("classpath:trace-context.xml")
@PropertySource("classpath:spring.properties")
public class ApplicationContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

// Maps resources path to webapp/resources
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

// Only needed if we are using @Value and ${...} when referencing properties
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySources = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] { 
            new ClassPathResource("spring.properties") };
    propertySources.setLocations(resources);
    propertySources.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return propertySources;
}

// Provides internationalization of messages
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasename("messages");
    return source;
}
}
```

ThymeleafConfig class:

```
@Configuration 
public class ThymeleafConfig {

@Bean 
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setOrder(1);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean 
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

@Bean 
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return resolver;
}   
}
```

SpringSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("mkyong").password("123456").roles("USER");
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123456").roles("ADMIN");
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("dba").password("123456").roles("DBA");
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
  }

@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/users")
        //.failureUrl("/login.html?authfailed=true")
        .and()
    .logout()
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
}
```

SecurityInit class:

```
public class SecurityInit extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

[image: Screenshot of project folders and files]

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing pages and templates?

Comment: What happens if you name your page `login2`? There can be some surprising issues with the specific name `login`, since Spring Security provides the default form.

Comment: @mylenereiners That's not the problem. Thymeleaf templates are HTML pages.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error if I name my page to login2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a conflict with the resolvers of thymeleaf and springSecurity. You have set your loginPage configuration as 'login' and thymeleaf is expecting 'login.html'. Have you tried to change .loginPage("/login") for .loginPage("/login.html") ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the suffix code from config.

```
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

Answer (score -1):

In the ThymeleafProperties class that the default prefix for views is `classpath:/templates/` and the default suffix is `.html`. So change your `html` to `src/main/resources/templates/login.html`, as shown in the following image

[image: Image depicting the file naming notation]